# File not found when including additional independency C++ visual studio

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, .lib

I'm using Visual studio 2015

I'm trying to add some libraries(.lib) to my project. I add them by going to `Project->Properties` and go to the tab `Linker`. I go to `General` and fill in the `Additional Library Directories`. After that I go to `Input`and fill in the files I want to include at `Additional Dependencies`. (These files are located in the `Additional Library Directories`).

But when I run my program it says:
The program can't start because filename.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I know these .lib files work with the dll file. But when I add the .dll file also to the additional dependencies it says: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read 0x2C8.

Thats because my dll file shouldn't be there, so how can I include this dll file or let it work with my .lib files to run my program?

Comment: You should enter the static libraries (.lib) to the Additional Libraries. However, the DLL must be in one of the looked up locations (working directory, a directory listed in the PATH env variable, the system folder, etc.).

Comment: When I add the .dll files to the same directory as where my project is, it still gives the same error. I saw when I add the .dll files in my C://Windows it DOES work. But I don't want them to be in my Windows folder.

Comment: Not where your project, but where you're project output is. The working directory, the directory from where your executable is runnning.

Comment: and How can I add these .dll files in my project directory so my computers loads them from here instead of my working directory?